# Regex for a match in maximum within 2 lines

Tags: java, regex

I cannot seem to figure this out.
I want something that match 2 KEYWORDS: KEYWORD1 and KEYWORD2. Order doesn't matter KEYWORD2 can appear before or after KEYWORD1. In between KEYWORD1 and KEYWORD2 can be other characters, **but maximum scan within 2 lines**.

Obviously KEYWORD1 and 2 are just a placeholder.

Should-match example:

```
"I saw KEYWORD1 walking around with KEYWORD2 yesterday"
"I saw KEYWORD1 walking around with \n KEYWORD2 yesterday"
"KEYWORD2 was spotted playing with KEYWORD1."
"KEYWORD2KEYWORD1 are best buddies."
```

Should not match example

```
"I saw KEYWORD1 walking around with \n\n KEYWORD2 yesterday."
```

I was advised with this Regex, a look ahead (which doesn't consume) as long as there is a KEYWORD1 present, continue with finding KEYWORD2. But this will find match due to more than one newlines.

```
(?i)(?=[\\w\\s]*(KEYWORD1))[\\w\\s]*(KEYWORD2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(KEYWORD1.*\n?.*KEYWORD2)|(KEYWORD2.*\n?.*KEYWORD1)
```

Comment: Brilliant! Why I didn't think of that. Thanks @ka3ak. PS: you got an extra \n?.*

Comment: @RonPringadi Ah ok. I've miscounted. I've edited the answer.